# Flutter read/write to external storage with Android SDK 30+

Tags: android, flutter

Developing an Android app in Flutter targetting Android SDK 30+.

I want to read and write data (xml files) to something like:

```
/storage/emulated/0/CustomDirectory/example.xml
```

Reading around I guess I'm supposed to use `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` so I wrote a `MethodChannel` which allows me to open the `SelectDialog` just fine. (I've trimmed all the try-catch and error handling for brevity)

```
private fun selectDirectory() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
    intent.addFlags(
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION or
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
    )
    startActivityForResult(intent, 100)
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    val uri = data.data!!
    contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
        uri,
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
    )
    return uri.toString())
}
```

I can call this from Flutter, it opens the "Select Directory" dialog, and I can choose my `CustomDirectory`, which then returns me a Content URI of:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ACustomDirectory
```

How do I convert that into a Flutter Directory?

In Flutter, I can call `Directory.fromUri(...)` but that just throws

```
Unsupported operation: Cannot extract a file path from a content URI
```

So I'm a little unsure of where to go from here, do I need to change the flags of my `Intent` or am I doing something very wrong somewhere?

Comment: First: remove those flags fron that intent. They make no sense. They have no effect.

Comment: `want to read and write data (xml files) to something like:

/storage/emulated/0/CustomDirectory/example.xml
` On Android 30 devices use: 
/storage/emulated/0/Documents/CustomDirectory/example.xml

Comment: @blackapps thanks for the notes on the flags, will remove. Problem is another application is actually writing those files into that location so it's set outside my control. I guess eventually when that updates it will no longer be able to write to that location?

Comment: Then you cannot write to that directory now with file io. Then indeed use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user pick that directory and use saf code to access it. No file io any more.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do, problem is Flutter doesn't seem to know what SAF is.

Comment: Hard to believe. That action is saf. You should not try to extract paths from an uri. Sorry i dont use Flutter...

Comment: @ChrisTurner did you able figure it out ? how to get the files list from  Directory.fromUri(...) !!??
As I am facing the same issue I really want to read the files  !

Comment: I ended up implementing `MethodChannel` calls in native Kotlin as I wasn't able to get it working in Dart

Comment: @ChrisTurner Can you please share that MethodChannel code ? as I want to implement the same :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be a long answer and a lot of the code is specific to my use case so if someone wants to reuse it, you might need to tweak things.

Basically with the changes in Android 30+ I wasn't able to get permissions to write to a directory on the user's phone that wasn't my apps own directory without requesting the dreaded `manage_external_storage`.

I solved this by doing this with native Kotlin then calling those methods via an interface in Dart.

First starting with the Kotlin code

```kotlin
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "package/Main"

    private var pendingResult: MethodChannel.Result? = null

    private var methodCall: MethodCall? = null

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        MethodChannel(
                flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
                CHANNEL
        ).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            val handlers = mapOf(
                    "getSavedRoot" to ::getSavedRoot,
                    "selectDirectory" to ::copyDirectoryToCache,
                    "createDirectory" to ::createDirectory,
                    "writeFile" to ::writeFile,
            )
            if (call.method in handlers) {
                handlers[call.method]!!.invoke(call, result)
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }
```

This sets up our `MainActivity` to listen for methods named in the `setMethodCallHandler` method.

There are plenty of examples you can find for how to implement basic IO functions in Kotlin so I won't post them all here, but an example of how to open a set a content root and handle the result:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

//...

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private fun selectContentRoot(call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result) {

        pendingResult = result

        try {
            val browseIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
            startActivityForResult(browseIntent, 100)
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            Log.e("selectDirectory", " error", e)
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            val uri: Uri = data?.data!!

            contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                    uri,
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            )

            contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                    uri,
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
            )

            return pendingResult!!.success(uri.toString())
        }

        return
    }

//..
```

Now to invoke that code in Dart I created an interface named `AndroidInterface` and implemented

```dart
class AndroidInterface {
  final _platform = const MethodChannel('package/Main');

  final _errors = {
    'no persist document tree': FileOperationError.noSavedPersistRoot,
    'pending': FileOperationError.pending,
    'access error': FileOperationError.accessError,
    'exists': FileOperationError.alreadyExists,
    'creation failed': FileOperationError.creationFailed,
    'canceled': FileOperationError.canceled,
  };

  String? _root;

  // invoke a method with given arguments
  Future<FileOperationResult<String>> _invoke(
    String method, {
    bool returnVoid = false,
    String? root,
    String? directory,
    String? subdir,
    String? name,
    Uint8List? bytes,
    bool? overwrite,
  }) async {
    try {
      final result = await _platform.invokeMethod<String>(method, {
        'root': root,
        'directory': directory,
        'subdir': subdir,
        'name': name,
        'bytes': bytes,
        'overwrite': overwrite,
      });

      if (result != null || returnVoid) {
        final fileOperationResult = FileOperationResult(result: result);

        fileOperationResult.result = result;

        return fileOperationResult;
      }

      return FileOperationResult(error: FileOperationError.unknown);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      final error = _errors[e.code] ?? FileOperationError.unknown;

      return FileOperationResult(
        error: error,
        result: e.code,
        message: e.message,
      );
    }
  }

  Future<FileOperationResult<String>> selectContentRoot() async {
    final result = await _invoke('selectContentRoot');

    // release currently selected directory if new directory selected successfully
    if (result.error == FileOperationError.success) {
      if (_root != null) {
        await _invoke('releaseDirectory', root: _root, returnVoid: true);
      }
      _root = result.result;
    }

    return result;
  }

//...
```

Which basically sends the requests via `_platform.invokeMethod` passing the name of the method, and the arguments to send.

Using a factory pattern you can implement this interface device running 30+ and use standard stuff for Apple and devices running 29 and below.

Something like:

```dart
abstract class IOInterface {
  
//...

  /// Select a subdirectory of the root directory
  Future<void> selectDirectory(String? message, String? buttonText);
}
```

And a factory to decide what interface to use

```dart
class IOFactory {
  static IOInterface? _interface;

  static IOInterface? get instance => _interface;

  IOFactory._create();

  static Future<IOFactory> create() async {
    final component = IOFactory._create();

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final androidInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
      final sdkInt = androidInfo.version.sdkInt;

      _interface = sdkInt > 29 ? AndroidSDKThirty() : AndroidSDKTwentyNine();
    }

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      _interface = AppleAll();
    }

    return component;
  }
}
```

Finally, the implementation for 30+ could look like

```dart
class AndroidSDKThirty implements IOInterface {
  final AndroidInterface _androidInterface = AndroidInterface();

  @override
  Future<void> selectDirectory(String? message, String? buttonText) async {
    final contentRoot = await _androidInterface.getContentRoot();
    //...
  }
```

Hopefully, this is enough to get you started and pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing :)