# Write file to directory with allowed access on Android

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions, file-writing, android-external-storage

I want to export a save file so the user can later import it into the app again later, but how do I allow exporting to a directory outside the app dir (/Android/com.app/files)

```dart
if (!(await Permission.storage.request().isGranted)) return;

final String? exportPath = await FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath();

if (exportPath == null) return;

File exportFile = await File(
  "$exportPath/zs_tracker_data.sav",
).create(recursive: true);
```

This code is backed by these gradle properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

With `compileSdkVersion 33` selected, and these permissions:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

All of these above allows me to get a path, and then get this prompt:[image: Allow Access In Dir Prompt]

However, even when I press 'Allow', I am not allowed to touch that directory and get: `Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Backups/zs_tracker_data.sav' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)`

I've considered allowing `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, but then my app won't be allowed on Play Store, since the only reasons it needs storage permissions are for creating backups and importing backups. I've also seen this post: [Flutter read/write to external storage with Android SDK 30+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69533579/flutter-read-write-to-external-storage-with-android-sdk-30), but the answer blows over my head completely and seems horribly over complex for my simple backup export/importing...

How do I go about this in a decently simple way? I just want to be able to save the exported file somewhere where the user can easily find it

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use a totally different approach which doesn't require any permissions. Use *sharing* to allow a user to choose whatever a destination she/he desires. For example using [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) plugin:

```
Share.shareFiles(['<path to file>'], text: 'Export file');
```

Comment: Wow... That's certainly one way to go about it! But I think it will be great for now, thank you ;)