# How can I save files on android 13 (API 33) by using Flutter (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, storage, android-permissions, android-external-storage

Files are not only media files. It may also be **.pdf, .zip, .xls and etc..**

The external storage permission is permanently denied on API 33. 
So, we are not able to save like this method ->

```
String path = 'This is external storage path';
File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes)
```

My app is working well on android 11, 10, 9 and etc..
I have set storage permissions on AndroidManifest.xml but it is not work on android 13. 
**So, How can I save files at external storage on android 13?**
I know a way to set **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** on AndroidManifest.xml. But it is restricted by PlayStore. So, it doesn't ok for us.

**So, What is the best way to save files on Android 13's external storage?**

I have seen [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73620790/android-13-how-to-request-write-external-storage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [a package](https://pub.dev/packages/cr_file_saver) to solve this case.
This way is very easy and working fine.
So, I set [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/cr_file_saver) as the best solution for now.
If anyone have a better way, I will define it as answer.

Comment: how did you solve it, I am getting platform exception in android 13, would you please share the code?

Answer (score 1):

Did you see that questions? It seems it has almost the same issue as you have with saving files locally - [Write file to directory with allowed access on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73012513/write-file-to-directory-with-allowed-access-on-android) and also try to check out this answer - [Flutter read/write to external storage with Android SDK 30+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69533579/flutter-read-write-to-external-storage-with-android-sdk-30)

in the second case you should work with native code (kotlin or java)

Comment: Thank your participation. I think, [this](https://pub.dev/packages/cr_file_saver) may be the best solution for now.